# setting a counter within nested for loop

Tags: django, for-loop, counter

I'm building a ecommerce site with django and i'm working on the page that lists out all the orders.  I want to set a counter that will number the orders from 1 to whatever.  However if i set a for loop to do this, Won't the number get reset everytime i jump back to the original forloop?

right now im using the primary key to number all the orders, but i want to change that to be from 1-whatever.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Order page

{% for location, orders in orderlocations.items %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>Location</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>Order</td>
            <td>Order Quantity</td>
            <td>Delivered</td>

        </tr>

        {% for ord in orders %}
            {% for food in ord.orderitem_set.all %}

            <tr>
                {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                    <td>{{ord.pk}}</td>
                    <td>{{ord.time}}</td>
                    <td>{{ord.location}}</td>
                    <td>{{ord.user.first_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ord.user.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{ord.user.get_profile.phone}}</td>

                {% else %}
                    <td colspan="4"></td>
                {% endif %}

                    <td>{{food.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{food.quantity}}</td>

                <td>
                    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %} 
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="order-id" value="{{ ord.pk }}"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="action=" value="toggledelivery"/>
                            <button type="button">{% if not ord.delivered %}Not {% endif %}Delivered</button>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}        
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

    </table>  

{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but the question is not clear to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `<td>{{ord.pk}}</td>` use `<td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>`.

The for-loops each have their own scope. If you wanted the outer loop's counter you would use `forloop.parentloop.counter`

[Django For-Loops](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)